# string concatenate with nil object in swift

Tags: ios, core-data, nsstring, swift2

I am trying find string value from coredata entity which some time return either string value or nil value. I have to join that value with another string but when its return nil application crashed 
my code snippet

```
let objtest = (TblObjectValue.findOrCreate(["objectId":dicCurrent.valueForJSON("Id")]) as TblObjectValue)
tablecell.lblTitle?.text = "Value: "+objtest.displayValue!
```

Where *TblObjectValue is NSManagedObject* and  *objectId(NSString) and displayValue(NSString) are attribute* of TblObjectValue entity 
`application crash if displayValue is null`

`i want it in one line` beacuse i used following code  many time in my project

```
tablecell.lblTitle?.text = (dicCurrent.valueForJSON("CardLabel") as? String)!+": "+(TblObjectValue.findOrCreate(["objectId":dicCurrent.valueForJSON("Id")]) as TblObjectValue).displayValue!
```

Comment: `i want it in one line`: Source code real estate doesn't cost a dime. You'd better break down your statement in several lines using proper optional binding, rather than stuffing everything in one line for the sake of it and ending with unreadable, unsafe and unmaintanable code.

Answer (score 2):

Check it before do anything:

```
if objtest.displayValue != nil {
  tablecell.lblTitle?.text = "Value: "+objtest.displayValue!
}
```

Comment: actually i want it in one line my real code is   ----  tablecell.lblTitle?.text = (dicCurrent.valueForJSON("CardLabel") as? String)!+": "+(TblObjectValue.findOrCreate(["objectId":dicCurrent.valueForJSON("Id")]) as TblObjectValue).displayValue!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't

```
tablecell.lblTitle?.text = "Value: "+ (objtest.displayValue ?? "")
```

do the trick?

Comment: i tried already 
tablecell.lblTitle?.text = (dicCurrent.valueForJSON("CardLabel") as? String)!+": "+(TblObjectValue.findOrCreate(["objectId":dicCurrent.valueForJSON("Id")]) as TblObjectValue).displayValue! ?? "" 
but its not work

Comment: Of course it does answer the question - it's just formulated as a question.